# what is the docker-compose.exporters.yml in this repo and how to call it?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was reviewing a repo for a monitoring system and I saw a docker composer like this\

[Repo link](https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockprom)
[image]

I ran the project as usual by docker-compose up, but I want to know what is docker-compose.exporters.yml? and when it is called or how it is called.

when I run docker-compose up, will it trigger docker-compose.exporters.yml  as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an alternative configuration for `docker-compose`. By default compose will use the file `docker-compose.yaml`, but you can point it at a different configuration file with the `-f` (`--file`) option, as in:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.exporters.yml up
```

The purpose of the file is described in [issue #5](https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockprom/issues/5); it's for running just the metric exporters on additional hosts so that you can add them to your prometheus configuration.

> when I run docker-compose up, will it trigger docker-compose.exporters.yml as well?

It will not; that file will only be used if you explicitly reference it on the command line.